# How do I resubmit app for review in new platform?

Tags: android

I recently uploaded an app to play store, but the app got rejected on copyright issues.

I used the word "tiktok" in the title of the app, since my app is a country specific version of the same concept.

I have changed this now, but I cannot seem to find a way to "resubmit" the app for review in the new play store interface.

I have also changed app icon, and featured graphic.

However, I cannot seem to find a way to delete previous screenshots I uploaded, for phone and for tablets etc.

My first question is, how can I delete previous screenshots?

My second question is, how do I resubmit this app for review?

The dashboard where "All apps" are listed, its not showing the "resubmit for review" button there.
The production release section is also not showing the resubmit button.

How do I resubmit this app for review?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Screenshots: In the "Main store listing" move your mouse over the screenshot. In the top right corner you will see a trash bin icon. Simply click it to delete the screenshot.
Then upload your new ones. Then click save. It will automatically be put up to review.

Google is very sensitive about using trademarks in the apps promotional content.
No other App names in the Title, Short Description and Long Description.
No other Apps Icons or graphics in your own graphics.

For a new apk. Simply increment the version number by one and upload it into production.

Comment: I am on screen reader, and cannot do that mouse over thing. Is there any other way to delete screenshot? From what you wrote, once changes are done, app will automatically go into review, and I need not click any resubmit button, right?